# Why isn't my program stopping where I tell it to?

Tags: visual-c++

I'm trying to write my program to clear the screen and display a simple 'help' section when the user calls for it. The program is then supposed to wait for the user to hit enter before clearing the screen again and redirecting back to the 'screen' they were previously on (in a different function).  However, for some reason the program isn't waiting for the user input before continuing, and the help screen isn't displaying at all.  Maybe a different set of eyes can see something I'm missing?

As far as I know, the `cin.get();` function should work to pause my program but it isn't doing what it's supposed to.  I expect that the problem is actually in the help section, but I don't know how it could be screwing up.  Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

string Input;

bool EndGame = false;

void Help();

//You can ignore this function, I just included it because it's called multiple times
void Clear(int Cursorx, int Cursory)
{
    HANDLE                     hStdOut;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    DWORD                      count;
    DWORD                      cellCount;
    COORD                      homeCoords = { Cursorx, Cursory };

    hStdOut = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
    if (hStdOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {return;}

    /* Get the number of cells in the current buffer */
    if (!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( hStdOut, &csbi )) {return;}
    cellCount = csbi.dwSize.X *csbi.dwSize.Y;

    /* Fill the entire buffer with spaces */
    if (!FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hStdOut,(TCHAR) ' ',cellCount,homeCoords,&count)) {return;}

    /* Fill the entire buffer with the current colors and attributes */
    if (!FillConsoleOutputAttribute(hStdOut,csbi.wAttributes,cellCount,homeCoords,&count)) return;

    /* Move the cursor home */
    SetConsoleCursorPosition( hStdOut, homeCoords );
}

void Help()
{       
    Clear(0,0);
    bool cont = false;
    cout <<"To move, use the 2,4,6,8 keys on the numpad or WASD"<< endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout <<"K - Stats"<< endl;
    cout <<"M - Map (once aquired)"<< endl;
    cout <<"J - Save"<< endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout <<"Press Enter to Continue"<< endl;

    cin.get();

    Clear(0,0);
}

void main()
{
    string Input;

    Center("THE DUNGEON");
    Center("type 'go' to start");
    Center("type 'load' to load previous game");
    Center("type 'h' to see all key commands");
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cin >> Input;

    /*if (Input == "test")
    {
        Test();
    }
    else if (Input == "go")
    {
        start();
    }
    else if (Input == "load")
    {
        Load();
    }*/
    else if (Input == "h")
    {
        Help();
    }

    if (EndGame == true)
    {
        Clear(0,0);
        Center("Thank you for Playing!  Return soon!");
    }

    Sleep(5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `cin.ignore()` just before `cin.get()` to get rid of previous value in input buffer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't even think that cin.get(); was reading from previous text.  I'm still kind of new at this.  My program works exactly as I want it to.  Thanks!